# Error when command is used twice before process ends [Discord.py Rewrite]

Tags: python, discord.py

This is my rock paper scissors code. If a game is ongoing and someone or you yourself uses the command, there will be an error where the bot keep spamming the message : 'What is your choice? (r)ock, (p)aper, (s)cissors or (q)uit'

How can I get rid of the spamming 'What is your choice? (r)ock, (p)aper, (s)cissors or (q)uit'?

```
@client.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['rps'])
@commands.guild_only()
async def game(ctx):
    await ctx.send(
        'Hello, ' + ctx.message.author.mention + '? Wanna play a round of Rock, Paper, Scissors?')

    wins = 0
    losses = 0
    ties = 0

    while True:
        await ctx.send('%s Wins, %s Losses, %s Draws \n' % (wins, losses, ties))
        while True:
            await ctx.send('What is your choice? (r)ock, (p)aper, (s)cissors or (q)uit')  
            player = await client.wait_for('message') 
            print(str(player))
            if player.content == 'q':
                await ctx.send('Game succesfully quitted.')
                return
            if player.content == 'r' or player.content == 'p' or player.content == 's':
                break

        if player.content == 'r':
            await ctx.send('Rock against...')
        elif player.content == 'p':
            await ctx.send('Paper against...')
        elif player.content == 's':
            await ctx.send('Scissors against...')

        randomnum = random.randint(1, 3)
        if randomnum == 1:
            computer = 'r'
            await ctx.send('Rock!')
        elif randomnum == 2:
            computer = 'p'
            await ctx.send('Paper!')
        elif randomnum == 3:
            computer = 's'
            await ctx.send('Scissors!')

        if player.content == computer:
            await ctx.send("It's a Draw!")
            ties = ties + 1
        elif player.content == 'r' and computer == 's':
            await ctx.send('You win!')
            wins = wins + 1
        elif player.content == 'r' and computer == 'p':
            await ctx.send('The bot wins!')
            losses = losses + 1
        elif player.content == 'p' and computer == 'r':
            await ctx.send('You win!')
            wins = wins + 1
        elif player.content == 'p' and computer == 's':
            losses = losses + 1
            await ctx.send('The bot wins!')
        elif player.content == 's' and computer == 'p':
            await ctx.send('You win!')
            wins = wins + 1
        elif player.content == 's' and computer == 'r':
            await ctx.send('The bot wins!')
            losses = losses + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
player = await client.wait_for('message')
```

you must add check in this.

```
def check(msg, user):
  return user.author == ctx.message.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel
player = await client.wait_for('message', check=check())
```